# How to set a range element's thumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a little game using multiple range elements to set percentage of a class from the population.

Like:

```
<input type="range" id="Miners_r" value="50" min="0" max="100" step="1" >
<input type="range" id="Farmers_r" value="50" min="0" max="100" step="1" >
```

How could I prevent setting the others to a higher value than 100% added?
I would like to use js or jQuery to solve this.

`Miner_r.value + Farmers_r.value >= 100` in this case I should not be able to set the others to bigger than 0

If something is not clear due to my sillyness, please ask me a question about it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the JS code that you have tried?

Comment: I could not came up with anything working properly. It is not good nor working, I am ashamed of it. I used this function at an oninput. function checker(variable, sliderValueName) {
  if (variable + available_population >= assigned_populatin || variable > document.getElementById("sliderValueName").value) {} 
  else {
    document.getElementById("sliderValueName").value = variable;
  }
}

Comment: The 'variable' is the var of Miners or Farmers.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy. The logic you are looking for is:

1. Listen to the change in value of any one of the range element
2. Calculate the value allowed for other siblings so that the sum is 100
3. Set the other sibling to this value

In my code below, I assumed that there will be use cases where multiple siblings are involved—in that case, the remainder value will be distributed evenly among all the other siblings. It should also work well for your case.

p/s: I have given all your inputs a general class of `.range-group` just to simply the selection.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.range-group').on('change', function() {
    var $t = $(this),
        $s = $(this).siblings('.range-group');
    
    // Cap siblings values to 100 minus the current value.
    // The remainder of the values will be distribueted evenly among
    // all other siblings.
    $s.val((100 - $t.val())/$s.length);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" class="range-group" id="Miners_r" value="50" min="0" max="100" step="1" >
<input type="range" class="range-group" id="Farmers_r" value="50" min="0" max="100" step="1" >
```

Comment: It's not really working well. When I added 1 more  and changed the values, it went to 150% added. When one is set to 100% the others go down to 50% and not 0%. I try to solve it using this function but I will modify it somehow.

Comment: Probably an order of operation issue. Try this: `$s.val((100 - $t.val())/$s.length)`.